# Are Office 365 "for Students" and the new Microsoft Imagine Premium allowed in commercial usage?

Tags: license, office365, dreamspark

First quettion,
I have trouble finding these EULA,

[image: Office 365 License]

I have tried to search with google but I can't find it

> https://www.microsoft.com/online/mosa/MOSA2014Agr(NA)(ENG)(Nov2014)(HTML).htm
>   http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/d/4/3d42bdc2-6725-4b29-b75a-a5b04179958b/licensing_office365_proplus_in_volume_licensing.pdf
>   http://computershowcase.umich.edu/software/microsoft-service-agreement-office365.pdf

Are both of them allowed in commercial usage?

---

About the second question,
It is very clear that Dreamspark Premium cannot be used in commercial usage at all.
You can verify In this link at section four point c
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/jj900153.aspx

But what about the Imagine Premium?
As it written in this link,
https://imagine.microsoft.com/en-us/institutions/guidelines

> 4 Using the Subscription Benefits
>   ...
>   Your Subscription will provide you and your Authorized Users with access to certain Subscription Benefits expressly intended to support your education, teaching, **non-commercial research**, or efforts to design, develop, test, and demonstrate software applications for the above purposes.
>
> ---
>
> 6 Prohibited Use of Subscription Benefits
>   ...
>   The Subscription Benefits and associated website(s) may contain **e-mail services, bulletin board services, chat areas, forums, communities, personal web pages, calendars, photo albums, file cabinets, and/or other message or communication facilities designed to enable Authorized Users to communicate with others ("Communication Services").** You agree to instruct Authorized Users that they may use the Communication Services only to post, send, and receive messages and material that are proper and, when applicable, related to the particular Communication Service. By way of example, and not as a limitation, when using the Communication Services, Authorized Users may not:
>
> - Use the Communication Services in connection with surveys, contests, pyramid schemes, chain letters, junk email, spamming, or any duplicative or unsolicited messages (commercial or otherwise).
> - ...
> - Advertise or offer to sell or buy any goods or services for any business purpose, **unless such Communication Services specifically allows such messages**.

This subscription offers free Windows 10 Education, Visual Studio Enterprise 2017, Windows Server 2016, Visio 2016, Project Pro 2016, SQL Server 2016, and many other application which can also be used in commercial research and also commercial business.
It is ambiguous and unclear to me that the whole Microsoft Imagine Premium is allowed to use in commercial usage or not. If commercial research is not allowed, what about commercial business?

Comment: @Ramhound, found in google [in this link](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/DreamSpark/) `Until 2016, Microsoft Imagine was known as Microsoft DreamSpark. Other than the change in name, they are the same thing.`. If you do compare between [Dreamspark EULA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/jj900153.aspx) and [Imagine EULA](https://imagine.microsoft.com/en-us/institutions/guidelines) both are meant for STEM student, 5 words mentioned in DreamSpark EULA and 11 words mentioned in Imagine EULA

Comment: @Ramhound you has just delete the comment haha, yes, I glad that I find that it was the same thing confirmed by the wikipedia either https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Imagine citation 4 http://forest.watch.impress.co.jp/docs/news/1016602.html

Comment: Any down-voters can explain why?

Answer (score 2):

> Are both of them allowed in commercial usage?

Commercial use of a student Office 365 is prohibited by the terms of the license you agree to.

> Microsoft Imagine connects students with the tools, resources and experiences they need to elevate their skills for today's working world. Whether it's building a game, designing an app or launching a project, Microsoft Imagine helps students develop their ideas and boldly bring them to life.

In this context a student is a K-12 student.  K-12 students can be older than 13.  In the states somebody must be a legal adult to agree to an EULA.  Additionally it seems Dreamspark was merged into this program.  This means eligible college degree seeking students are eligible for this program also

> This subscription offers free Windows 10 Education, Visual Studio Enterprise 2017, Windows Server 2016, Visio 2016, Project Pro 2016, SQL Server 2016, and many other application which can also be used in commercial research and also commercial business.

The fact the program offers licenses to these programs doesn't change the terms of the license and the fact it's a program that does not allow commercial use.

Dreamspark was/is a program for college students who are seeking an eligible degree from a school which is a participant.

Comment: Thus, according to your answer, it means that the Microsoft has been obfuscated the EULA, so I can't sell my software by using Windows 10 Education or any business purposes ;sad;

Comment: would you like to help me to find where are the both Office 365 EULA? I can't find the appropriate EULA anywhere in the google

Comment: Unless you are a corporation, Microsoft doesn't really care, the semantics of what you can do and what you should do, is out of scope here

Comment: even if Microsoft doesn't care, I care, it's an agreement, we have to respect it, even if it looks priceless. Have you already found it?

Comment: @Unknown123 I won't be looking.  I already answered the question You asked

Comment: If I might ask, If you don't look for the agreement, then how do you know that commercial use of a student Office 365 is prohibited?

Comment: I have a license myself and read the EULA once before.  Let's not have an extended discussion in the comment section.

Comment: Please, would you like to show to me the EULA? I also need to read the EULA, just only one more, that's it

Comment: I won't be doing that.